# Python classes--Need explanation

Tags: python

I have a general question on the class definition and its use..THe below code from one of the book works fine but I have a general questions.

Here we have defined a class Point and creating 2 instance Point1 & Point2. When calculating the distance for point2, how can we pass the point1 object?

Isn't point1 the point object, whereas the other_point is reprented as a variable.

Im little confused.

Code:

```
import math
class Point:
    def move(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def reset(self):
        self.move(0, 0)
    def calculate_distance(self, other_point):
        print("Inside calculating distance")

        return math.sqrt(
                (self.x - other_point.x)**2 +
                (self.y - other_point.y)**2)

point1 = Point()
point2 = Point()
point1.reset()
point2.move(5,0)
print(point2.calculate_distance(point1))
```

Comment: This site is not for mentoring. Please read a tutorial on python classes, objects, and methods.

Comment: Aww c'mon! This is a programming forum, and this guy looks to be very new to python. Also, this wouldn't be the first time a mentoring style question has been asked on SO.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Neither the first nor last time, but I think it is right to discourage them.

Comment: @Marcin: I'm curious as to why you want to discourage them. I would think that that would be be counter to helping such OPs learn?

Comment: Where is the `__init__()` function? Is it not necessary in this context?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget SO does not exist to replace all other learning resources on the web. It exists to provide help in a question-and-answer format. Mentoring requests end up with pages incomprehensible to those who didn't follow the conversation, and format of the site makes the experience much more difficult for all parties. There are various channels for conversation on the internet, and mentoring is much better undertaken there.

Comment: @Michael `__init__` is always optional (unless some code tries to pass arguments to the call to the type, or some other magic is occurring).

Comment: @Marcin In that case what are `self.x` and `self.y` set to when `Point()` is called?

Comment: @Michael, nothing. They don't exist yet. `point3 = Point(); point3.calculate_distance(point1)` will throw an error.

Comment: @Marcin: From what I can tell, this question asks a question that follows the guidelines in [What kind of questions can I ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) and in [What not to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). I think it's a valid question. It's not like he's saying "I want to learn python. Where do I begin?" This is actually a specific programming question ("When calculating the distance for point2, how can we pass the point1 object?")

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Whether or not this question strictly falls within whatever documents you want to cite as defining the scope of questions (not a criticism of you - this is a problem that SO has), the thrust of it is "please teach me how to write and use methods, I can't understand my own code". That's the kind of thing best dealt with by tutorials and mentoring.

Comment: @Marcin: (no offence taken/intended). I get what you're saying. I suppose joining an SO chatroom might have even been a better choice. But then again, I'm clearly newer to SO than you are (You have ~3x my rep). Perhaps this would be a better question for meta. This very question could even be a case-in-point to discuss on such a post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the `self` variable does. So when you are inside the definition of a class, you can use `self` to identify the object whose data you are trying to manipulate.

For example, suppose you have a class called human (which has a member variable named `age`), and every year, you want to increase the age of that human by calling the `increment_age` function. Then, you could write the following code:

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self):
        self.age = 0

    def increment_age(self):
        self.age += 1

>>> h = Human()
>>> print h.age
0
>>> h.increment_age()
>>> print h.age
1
```

So you see, by calling `self`, you are referring to the object itself. In your example, this would translate to `self` referring to `point1`.

Now, suppose that in the `Human` class, we want to add a function that allows two humans to fight. In this case, one human would have to fight another human (suppose that fighting another human increases your life by one and decreases the other human's life by one). In that case, you could write the following function within the `Human` class:

```
def fight(self, other_human):
    self.age += 1
    other_human.age -= 1
```

Now:

```
>>> h1 = Human()
>>> h2 = Human()
>>> h1.age = 5
>>> h2.age = 3
>>> print h1.age
5
>>> print h2.age
3
>>> h1.fight(h2)
>>> print h1.age
6
>>> print h2.age
2
```

Thus you can see in this example that `h2` is the `other_human` in the `fight` function.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 5):

When you create a `Point` object, several things happen.

```
point1 = Point()
point2 = Point()
```

One of the things that happens is that any methods belonging to the `Point` class are *bound*. What this means is that one of the arguments in the method is *fixed*, so that it always refers to the instance created. Let's look at the definition of `calculate_distance`.

```
def calculate_distance(self, other_point):
    print("Inside calculating distance")

    return math.sqrt(
            (self.x - other_point.x)**2 +
            (self.y - other_point.y)**2)
```

You can probably guess which argument is fixed. When `Point()` is called and an instance is created, the `self` parameter of `calculate_distnace` is fixed so that it always refers to that instance. So whenever you do this:

```
point1.calculate_distance(x)
```

You're doing the equivalent of this:

```
Point.calculate_distance(point1, x)
```

And whenever you do this:

```
point2.calculate_distance(point1)
```

You're doing the equivalent of this:

```
Point.calculate_distance(point2, point1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your code, `point2.calculate_distance(point1)` calls `calculate_distance` with the object referred to by `point2` as `self`, and the object referred to by `point1` as `other_point`.

A good way to learn about these sorts of things is to use a visual debugger, and inspect the values in stack frames as the calls are made.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `calculate_distance`, `other_point` is the name used to refer to whatever object is passed as an argument.